# How to toggle between 2 RadioGroups in Android?

Tags: android

I have 2 Radio groups , and each radio group contains 2 Radiobuttons. I am trying to toggle between these 2 groups but so far unsuccessful. Any help would be appreciated.

---

```
        myGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
        myGroup3 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup3);
        myGroup3.clearCheck();
        myGroup2.clearCheck();

        myGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        myGroup3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);


myGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            // @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                    myGroup3.clearCheck();
            }
        });
    myGroup3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                    myGroup2.clearCheck();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you expand on exactly what you are trying to achieve? If you mean to make one group uncheck when one button in the other is checked, the above won't work. It will call clearCheck(); on both groups.

Comment: Hi anthropomo, yes that is exactly what I am trying to achieve,one group uncheck when one button in the other is checked.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? rather then having 2 radio groups why not 1 and add all radio buttons there?

Comment: Hi Christian , I am having 2 rows of RadioGroup,and the only way to achieve the 2 rows Layout is to use 2 RadioGroups, and that is what I am doing.

Comment: I'm guessing @user wants a radiogroup in a grid, which, AFAIK, is not possible otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the API here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html

EDIT:

Not happy about how long it took, but I figured this out. Turns out onCheckedChanged only passes -1 for the checkedId when the group is already clear. If a box has just been unchecked, its ID is still passed.

You can do this:

```
    myGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if(checkedId != -1 &&
                ((RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId)).isChecked()){
                myGroup3.clearCheck();
            }
        }
    });
    myGroup3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if(checkedId != -1 &&
                        ((RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId)).isChecked()){
                    myGroup2.clearCheck();
                }
        }
    });
```

Or, probably a little more sensibly, have the activity implement the listener and this part is outside of the onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    if(checkedId != -1 && ((RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId)).isChecked()){
        if(group == myGroup2){
            myGroup3.clearCheck();
        }
        else if(group == myGroup3){
            myGroup2.clearCheck();
        }
        // And your switch for whatever you want to happen based on the
        // selected button goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi anthropomo, I did try the above but not working correctly; when you click on the first group, is selected,but when clicking on the second group everything is cleared, so you have to click twice on the second group to get selected...I did the same code for group3 as well..

Comment: I ckecked and everything is ok. What I doubt is that maybe is not supposed to be inside:  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {... again not sure...

Comment: I am sure that there is a solution to all of this.I was thinking about a switch , and case if it could be implemented for the 2 listeners ...

Comment: Finally you made it anthropomo and is working beautifully, Thanks again ! :)

Comment: yes man,I duno how to give you more marks ? I was close to your solution but didn't hit it in the nail like you did ! sometimes my brain stop when spending too much time  on something without getting into the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I came up with.

```
radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
    RadioButton[] tempradbutton1 = {
            (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1),
            (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2) };
    RadioButton[] tempradbutton2 = {
            (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio4),
            (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio5) };
    radbutton1 = tempradbutton1;
    radbutton2 = tempradbutton2;
    for (int i = 0; i < radbutton1.length; i++) {
        radbutton1[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                radioGroup2.clearCheck();
            }
        });
        radbutton2[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                radioGroup1.clearCheck();

            }
        });
    }
```

Rather then using **setOnCheckedChangeListener**, use **onClickListener** for every radiobutton exist on the radiogroup.

XML:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
</RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1" >
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Hi Christian.Thanks for the solution but trying to figure out from where you got radio0, and radio3, as I dont have more than 4 buttons, 2 in each groups, are they added or hidden radiobuttons ?

Comment: radio0 and radio3 are added inside the radiogroup in the XML. Just remove the radio0 and radio3 in the code above if you have only 2 buttons.

Comment: I have added the xml. I hope it helped.